# How Azure cost for an AppService?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cost-calculation

There is only 1 App service is running.
I have scaled up to B1 plan for my App Service on 9 July 2023.
and on 10 July it costs me 82.75 INR and on 11 July cost is around 212.33 INR.
And then I stopped an app service at 11 July 8 PM after that there is no resource use.
please find same in below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrdYF.png)

I have few questions:

How much mac it can cost per day for B1 plan?
as B1 plan is for 4299 INR, so will it cost more that this? if all resources used?
If my app service is stopped, then average how much should it cost per day?
Please help me to understand this points.

I tried to review cost management and billing analysis but this details are not enough for me to understand As I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PRATHMESH CHOPADE,

The cost of an Azure App Service on the B1 plan can vary depending on the usage of resources such as CPU, memory, and storage.

I understand you have already checked the cost management; you may also use the Azure pricing calculator to estimate the cost of your app service based on your expected usage of resources.

If your App Service is stopped, then you should not be charged anything for the App Service itself. However, you may still be charged for other resources such as storage, database, etc. that are associated with your App Service.
To get a better understanding of the costs associated with your App Service, you can check the Azure portal for detailed usage and billing information. You can also use the Azure pricing calculator to estimate the costs for your App Service based on your usage and requirements.

From the **Azure pricing calculator**. Just as an example (with no other associated resources considered)
https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/calculator/
[image: Azure Pricing calculator here]

From [Azure docs FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-manage-costs#how-youre-charged-for-azure-app-service) : **How you're charged for Azure App Service**

•   You're charged an hourly rate based on the pricing tier of your App Service plan, prorated to the second.

•   The charge is applied to each scaled-out instance in your plan, based on the amount of time that the VM instance is allocated.

You may be interested to monitor your app service usage regularly to avoid unexpected charges. You can set up alerts in the Azure portal to notify you when your usage of resources exceeds a certain threshold.

- For any questions related to your subscription or billing, you may
  file a (free) support ticket with our : [Azure support team create an
  Azure support request.](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)

**Reference docs:**

[Plan and manage costs for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-manage-costs#how-youre-charged-for-azure-app-service)

[How much does my App Service plan cost?](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#how-much-does-my-app-service-plan-cost)